# how to add on_press function on a OneLineAvatarIconListItem added from main.py??(python and kivymd)

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want to add an onpress statement for my `OneLineAvatarIconListItem` named `pluto` . I want to open another screen when pressed its items but I can not understand how to put that statement .

The code is supposed to take some input of ingredients and then I have a file in which I have the name of the recipe ingredients and recipe.
here's my code(sorry for silly names)

**MAIN.PY:**

```
import pandas as pd
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineAvatarIconListItem

Builder.load_file('design.kv')
Window.size = (300, 500)

fridge_items = []
tim = []


class FridgeScreen(Screen):
    def add_item(self):
        global lst
        i = 0
        fridge_items.append(self.ids.inp.text)
        self.ids.inp.text = ''
        for x in range(len(fridge_items)):
            lst = OneLineAvatarIconListItem(text=fridge_items[i])
            i += 1
        self.ids.list.add_widget(lst)

    def search_recipe(self):
        book = pd.read_csv('RECIPE_BOOK.csv')
        ingredients = book['Ingredients']
        recipe_except = book.drop(columns='Recipe')
        lst2 = []
        recipe_freq = {}

        for items in fridge_items:
            for i in ingredients:
                if items in i:
                    lst2.append(i)

        for recipe in lst2:
            if recipe in recipe_freq:
                recipe_freq[recipe] += 1
            else:
                recipe_freq[recipe] = 1

        top_recipe = sorted(recipe_freq.items(),
                            key=lambda kv: kv[1],
                            reverse=True)

        z = 0
        for items in top_recipe:
            tommy = recipe_except[recipe_except['Ingredients'] == top_recipe[z][0]].index.values
            foo = recipe_except['Name'][int(tommy)]
            tim.append(foo)
            z += 1

        a = 0
        for it in range(len(tim)):
            pluto = OneLineAvatarIconListItem(text=tim[a])
            self.recipe_screen.ids.recipe.add_widget(pluto)
            pluto.on_press()
            a += 1


class FullRecipesScreen(Screen):
    pass


class RecipeScreen(Screen):
    pass


class RootScreen(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return RootScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

**.KV FILE:**

```
<FridgeScreen>:
    Screen:
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            MDToolbar:
                title: 'KITCHEN'
                left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x : print(x)]]
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                padding: 10

                MDTextField:
                    id: inp
                    hint_text: 'enter your ingredients'
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: 200

                ScrollView:
                    MDList:
                        id: list

            GridLayout:
                cols: 2
                size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
                padding: 10
                spacing: 80
                MDRectangleFlatButton:
                    text: 'search for recipes'
                    on_press: root.search_recipe()
                    on_press: root.manager.current = 'recipe_screen'

                MDFloatingActionButton:
                    icon: "plus"
                    on_press: root.add_item()


<RecipeScreen>:
    Screen:
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                id: recipe
                OneLineAvatarIconListItem:


<FullRecipesScreen>:
    Label:
        id: ingredients
        text: 'kuch bhi'
    Label:
        id: full_recipe
        text: 'bakwaas'


<RootScreen>:
    FridgeScreen:
        id: fridge_screen
        recipe_screen: recipe_screen
        name:
            'fridge_screen'

    RecipeScreen:
        id: recipe_screen
        fridge_screen: fridge_screen
        name:
            'recipe_screen'

    FullRecipesScreen:
        id: full_recipes_screen
        name:
            'full_recipes_screen'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your python code, where you create the `OneLineAvatarIconListItem`, you can specify `on_press`, like this:

```
    for x in range(len(fridge_items)):
        lst = OneLineAvatarIconListItem(text=fridge_items[i], on_press=partial(print, fridge_items[i]))
        i += 1
```

The use of `partial` sets the method and its arguments to be called. Of course, you can use any available method in place of `print`.